# In C#, how do I highlight selected item in a listview?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, highlight

In c# winforms, I have a listview with some images. The user can select one image, but when he leavs the listview i need to keep highlighting the item that he selected.
also, when the form is open, the data of the form is loaded from the DB. One data is the name of the image in the listview, I need to highlight the image that was loaded from the DB.

Comment: can you post code that you've worked?

Comment: Matthew Watson in the following answer , solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the [ListView.HideSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.hideselection.aspx) property to false.

Answer (score 0):

ListView.HideSelection set to false will override color on selected items.
If you want keep HideSelection set to false and show hightlight, you only can change it font.